# Backup multiple SQL databases across multiple servers

Tags: sql-server

I need to perform a nightly Full backup of multiple databases across multiple servers(100+).

These servers are SQLExpress so No SQL Agent, They are not Linked Severs either.

All DBs are in simple recovery mode.

Ideally, I want to centrally run 1 automated task to backup all of these dbs locally, then zip them locally (Compressed), and then move them to a central location.

That's my theory. is it possible?

All Servers are almost identical so uniformity of directories and names exists.

I have had a look at a few ways but no joy.

Cheers,

Rob.

Comment: If you want to avoid running scripts by hand you *have* to use some kind of agent or task scheduler. That's what "automated" means.

Comment: Googling for "SQL Server Express Backup" returns [How to schedule and automate backups of SQL Server databases in SQL Server Express](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2019698) in the results. Have you checked this?

Comment: Why are they in simple recovery mode? Are they critical in anyway?

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for getting back to me, I have checked the link previously and im open to an agent/scheduler if I can apply it to this.  regarding the recovery mode, I have argued to change them but in theory we don't need them in full. Data is moved via File Transfer, NOT ETL, but I wont get into that as its the bane of my existence but in short, its annoying and not exactly best practice but its ok with the full process.

Comment: regarding the link, that looks like it will work for one server, but I can do that a number of ways, issue is, how do I cycle through a number of Servers?